# Am I performing the sign chart right?

Tags: calculus

So I have a function: $$g(x) = \frac{(2x-3)(3x+1)}{(x-4)(x+2)}$$

What I have so far is that if I set each factor greater than $0$ and then solve for $x$, I get that $$x > \frac{3}{2}, x > -{1\over 3}, x > 4, x > -2$$ and from each chart, after combining each individual chart together, i get that the pattern for the main function's chart would be $+ , -, +, -$ at the intervals $$-2 , -\frac{1}{3} , \frac{3}{2} , 4$$ Please correct me if my logic on this is right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve each factor equal to zero. Then divide the real numbers in regions and study the signs in each one. You should get

\begin{array}{cccccc} & (-\infty,-1/2) & (-2,-1/3) & (-1/3,3/2) & (3/2,4) & (4,\infty) \\ \mathrm{sign\: of}\: \: 2x-3 & - & -& -& + & +\\ \mathrm{sign\: of}\: \:3x+1 & - &- & + & + & +\\ \mathrm{sign\: of}\: \:x-4 & -& -& -& -& + \\\mathrm{sign\: of}\: \:x+2 & - & +& +& +& +\\\mathrm{sign\: of}\: \:\dfrac{(2x-3)(3x+1)}{(x-4)(x+2)} & + & - & + & - & +\end{array}